# how to make div beside div

Tags: css, html, tags

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> This is my site </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bigger">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="adv">                        
            </div>  
            <div id="flag">
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#bigger
{
    height:1280px;
    width:880px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;    
    position:absolute    
}

#header
{
    background-color:Blue;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute
}

#adv
{
    background-color:Yellow;
    height:100%;
    width:35%    
}

#flag
{
    background-color:Red;
    height:100%;
    width:65%;    
    float:right
}
```

How do you make the flag div appear beside the adv div inside the header div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#adv` needs `float:left`, so it floats to the left (and `#flag` floats to the right, next to it, because of `float: right`).

Comment: Don't forget to give parent (in this case #header) overflow: hidden; so it will cover up floating divs as they may dynamically change their size in future. Avoid using static height of parent.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#header
    {
        background-color:Blue;
        height:10%;
        width:100%;
        position:relative
    }
    #flag
    {
    background-color:Red;
    height:100%;
    width:65%;  
    position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
Normally: (**somebody please correct me if I'm wrong on this**):

Widths and heights should be set in pixel height-width from the beginning instead of percentages because the code will be easier to work with later. Also, I'm sure both elements should float `left` because then the code will be again, easier to work with and will follow better code conventions. Also, I added margins for easier viewing. You can always delete them if you wish. Code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> This is my site </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bigger">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="adv">                        
            </div>  
            <div id="flag">
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#bigger
{
    height:1280px;
    width:880px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;    
    position:absolute    
}

#header
{
    background-color:Blue;
    height:90px;
    width:1290px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#adv
{
    background-color:Yellow;
    height:80px;
    width:840px;  
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#flag
{
    background-color:Red;
    height:80px;
    width:420px;   
    margin: 5px; 
    float:left;
}
```