# css, nav besides section with maximum width

Tags: html, css

I have placed a `nav` besides a `section` element. There are multiple questions about the same topic (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975961/css-placing-a-div-beside-a-div), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847728/how-to-make-div-beside-div), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650365/css-cant-place-two-divs-beside-each-other)). So in general I understand how to do it:

The below style sheet works, but with a **shortcoming**. As soon as the `section` element can no longer consume `80% width` it drops below the `nav` element.

```
nav { vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; }
section { position: relative; float: right; width: 80%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 0; }
........
<nav>Nav, left</nav><section>content, right</content>
```

What I actually want to achieve is having the `nav` to the left, and the `section` to the right consuming the **remaining** (!) space. Here is what I have tried:

1. No width with `section` does not work
2. Only giving `nav` a `width` does not work. I have tried to set a fixed `width` on `nav`, and no width on `section`
3. Reducing the `width` (e.g. to 60%) works better for smaller screens, but wastes a lot of space on wider screens. Remark: The 80% is somehow a compromise.

So how can I set up the css that the `section` consumes the right side **remaining** space (all of it)?

Comment: Can you put this up on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: @Bill https://jsfiddle.net/c3yd1a1h/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use positioning for this case. This is a case of:

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Or

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
|       | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Fixed-Fluid Model. In my snippet, I have demonstrated two kinds of examples. In the first case, the fluid is less in size. And the next has too long content.

**Snippet**

```css
.parent {position: relative; margin: 0 0 15px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; padding-left: 100px;}
.parent .fixed {position: absolute; left: 5px; width: 90px; background-color: #99f;}
.parent .fluid {background-color: #f99;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque animi placeat, expedita tempora explicabo facilis nulla fuga recusandae officia, maiores porro eaque, dolore et modi in sapiente accusamus id aut.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: will try this one out

Comment: And thanks for showing code snippets ;-) Never seen them before. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @HorstWalter Man you are old! `:(`